# How do I test an embedded ruby application?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have an embedded ruby interpreter running inside a c application, and a ruby class that acts an an interface to the c application. So it looks something like this:

```
class MyApi
  include RealCAPI

  def api_method
    some_call_to_c_api
  end 

end
```

Inside my ruby class that interacts with the api I have something like this.  I create an instance of the MyApi class and then call methods on that instance.

```
class Foo

  def initialize
    api = MyApi.new
    ...
    ...
  end

  def do_something
     bar = api.api_method
     ...
     ...
     ... 
     final_result  #is a function of Foo methods but depends on something from the api
  end

end
```

I would like to test Foo class with something like this:

```
describe Foo do
  it "should do something" do
    foo = Foo.new
    expect(foo.do_something to eq("something")
   end
end
```

The problem is that none of the calls to the api will work outside of the c application.
How do I test this Foo class?

Do I try to somehow test inside the c application?

Do I write a standalone test only "mock up" of the MyApi class, that mimics what happens in the c application?

I realize that if I mock up the api I can't really test it, but at least I will be able to test the classes that use it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to mock the api, as you said. What you are testing here is the ruby code, so you should probably stick to it and test *only* the ruby code.

You'll end up with something saying : provided my api does *something*, then my ruby code works exactly as specified. Which is good, and does not rely on wheter your api is working or not.

Of course, you'll probably have to write some test for your api. But keeping both tests separated seems like a good idea to me !

**edit**

Not sure if that's your question here, but this could easily be done by using something like

```
it "should do something" do 
  MyApi.any_instance.stub(:ping).and_return("pong") #so that when foo calls ping, the api returns "pong"
  foo = Foo.new
  expect....
end
```

Comment: Thanks,  I guess my have seen some info on any_instance, but must not have made the connection.  I ended up creating a mock class for the api (before i saw your edit).  I don't have many instances of the api, but I ended up with a small "factory" to return the mock class in test mode.  Either way I think you answered my question.